# Asp.net core role based access identity / roles make user table self referencing

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, roles, rbac

Hi I am trying to model an access control system where access is granted by role to certain actions. im trying to use asp.net core with identity and roles. it seems the default identity comes with its own tables for users. The users table i have need to be self referencing as a users will have managers who are also users.

is it possible to make the default table that comes with identity do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add additional properties to the already existing `IdentityUser`, all you have to do is inherit the IdentityUser class and then add your own properties then you go to the startup file and your dbcontext and do the following

```
public class InheritedUser : IdentityUser
{
   public bool HasTwoHeads { get; set;}

}
```

your **startup**

```
services.AddDefaultIdentity<InheritedUser>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<CustomDbContext>()                               .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
.AddDefaultUI(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI.UIFramework.Bootstrap4);
```

Then your Inherited **DbContext**

```
public class InheritedDbContext : IdentityDbContex<InheritedUser>
{

}
```

Comment: This is not working for me.    When I try to acess InheritedUser  it is always empty.  Yes there is a data object but it does not include any user information

Comment: in my _layout.cshtml  I have  /@inject ApplicationUser applicationUser  /@inject SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager;    I also have   /@if ( this.User.IsSysAdmin ( signInManager , applicationUser ) ){} which points at  Identityextension.IsSysAdmin()     application user is not filled in with anything meaningful.   It has a couple of guid filled in but it is not the proper information and everything else is null.  ApplicationUser applicationUser is not being populated